# Convert hex to byte the same way as in windows calculator

Tags: c#

When I'm converting 180 at dec value to byte in windows calculator I get -76.
At my code when I'm using `Convert.ToByte(180);` I get 180.
I need the result I get in windows calculator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a *signed* byte, you can convert using `unchecked((sbyte)180)`, which will give you -76.

Comment: 180 = 0xB4.  When you convert to byte the most significant bit is 1 which gives you a negative number.  When you read as integer you  have 0x000000B4 and most significate bit is zero giving you a positive number.  A signed byte goes from -127 to + 127. 180 is outside the range of a signed byte.